# How to avoid decreases and modify violation?

Tags: automated-tests, solidity, dafny

How I can avoid a decreases error, if my index will be not decreases after every iteration?
And why I am getting a modify clause on an object and an array, while I am using modify clause on them?

```
class ownerIndexs{
  var oi : map<int, int>;

  constructor(){
  new;
  }
}

class multiowned{

  var m_numOwners : int;
  var m_owners : array<int>;
  var m_ownerIndex : ownerIndexs;

method reorganizeOwners() returns (boo : bool)
  requires m_owners != null && m_ownerIndex != null
  requires  m_owners.Length >= 2
  requires 0 <= m_numOwners < m_owners.Length


  modifies this
  modifies this.m_owners 
  modifies this.m_ownerIndex;
 {
    var frees : int := 1;
    while (frees < m_numOwners)
    decreases m_numOwners - frees      //error 1
    invariant m_owners != null && m_numOwners < m_owners.Length
    invariant m_ownerIndex != null


    {
        while (frees < m_numOwners && m_owners[frees] != 0)
        decreases m_numOwners - frees
        invariant frees <= m_numOwners
        invariant m_owners != null && m_numOwners < m_owners.Length
        invariant m_ownerIndex != null
        {
          frees := frees +1;
        }

       while (m_numOwners > 1 && m_owners[m_numOwners] == 0)
       invariant m_owners != null && m_numOwners < m_owners.Length
       invariant m_ownerIndex != null
        {
          m_numOwners := m_numOwners-1;
       }
 if (frees < m_numOwners && m_owners[m_numOwners] != 0 && m_owners[frees] == 0)
        {
            m_owners[frees] := m_owners[m_numOwners]; //error 2
            m_ownerIndex.oi := m_ownerIndex.oi[m_owners[frees] := frees]; //error 3
            m_owners[m_numOwners] := 0;
        }
    }
    boo := true;
  }

}
```

I upload this code also in Dafny, where you can compile it again: https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/bYDH .
As you can see, I modified the array m_owner and also outsourced ownerIndex to an another object, because of other modify violations issues.
But here it seems like dafnys language is limited, isn`t it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write `modifies this.m_owners` but when you go to modify `this.m_owners`, Dafny doesn't know that `this.m_owners` still refers to the same object as it did at the beginning of the method.

Try adding these invariants to your while loops,

```
    invariant this.m_owners == old(this.m_owners)
    invariant this.m_ownerIndex == old(this.m_ownerIndex)
```

For the decreases clause, you'll need to prove to Dafny that `m_numOwners - frees` actually decreases, which doesn't seem true to me - it seems to me like it could be the case that both inner while-loop conditions will be false, in which case neither `m_numOwners` nor `frees` will change. That could be a bug in your code, or maybe you need more preconditions and invariants, I'm not sure of your intent.